# Refresh list of first fragment from third fragment

Tags: java, android

My question is **how to refresh the list on first fragment after work done on the third fragment ?**
Check this flow before any answers come out.
1. On MyActivity, I have the first fragment named as "**ABC**".
2. On button click of "**ABC**", move to second fragment "**JKL**" (without removing the first fragment).
3.  On button click of "**JKL**", move to third fragment "**XYZ**" and removes second fragment "**JKL**".
4. After work is done on third fragment "**XYZ**", third fragment "**XYZ**" removed and first fragment "**ABC**" comes front but unable to refresh the list on first fragment "**ABC**" since it is kept as it is.
5. I know the Interface, but it works as **one-to-one**.
6.  even, How do I send a string-value to the first fragment from the third fragment that I will use to refresh the list?
7.

> I cannot remove the first fragment due to preserving its last state as it is

Answer (score 1):

Since you are not replacing the ABC fragment, you can just ask the Fragment to refresh itself by having a public method in it, that is called by the parent Activity.

1. Hold the reference to your ABC fragment in the Activity
2. Have an interface in the XYZ fragment, that is implemented by the parent Activity
3. When something happens in XYZ, call the interface method, which in turn calls the ABC's refresh method

Ideally I would replace the ABC fragment and use the lifecycle callbacks to do the refresh. But for your case, you can follow the above steps.

Comment: Hi housefly, can you please share a simple code of your above answer. I am little bit confused by your flow in above answer.